# Special directives for assigning array with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

My simple `for` loop for parallelization in `OpenMP` is

```
    vector< double > xs; 
    vector< double > ys; 
    xs.resize(N);
    ys.resize(N);
    if(rank0) printf("Assigning points ...\n");
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        xs[i] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
        ys[i] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
    }
```

But this takes substantially longer when I include the `#pragma omp parallel for` than when I don't. This is often seen when I don't use a correct `reduction` or something like that, so I'm wondering if there is anything else I need to do for this `#pragma`.

Does this `for` loop need anything else in the `#pragma`?

Please note that this question is directly related to the use of `rand()`.

Comment: What platform are you on and what's the value of N?

Comment: Linux (thought I didn't think that would matter) and `N` is `500050000`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimising and why openmp is much slower than sequential way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371541/optimising-and-why-openmp-is-much-slower-than-sequential-way)

Comment: @OMGtechy: it may initially seem like a duplicate, but I don't think it is. The specific detail of using `rand()` is (I believe) highly relevant here (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My immediate guess would be that the problem stems from the fact that `rand()` uses a single seed that's updated every time you call `rand()`. This means that even though there's no conflict between the arrays you're writing to, every call to `rand()` is probably forcing synchronization between the threads.

There are various ways to handle this. One obvious one would be to use the new random number generation classes provided in C++11, with a separate random number generator object for each thread, something like this:

```
    std::mt19937_64 a;
    std::mt19937_64 b;

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> da;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> db;

#pragma omp parallel for private(a, b)
    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        xs[i] = da(a);
        ys[i] = db(b);
    }
```

At least in a quick test on my system, this runs in about 4 seconds single-threaded, and about 1 second with OpenMP enabled (and this is on a 4-core processor, so that's close to perfect scaling).

Note that if you're on a 32-bit system (or at least using a compiler that produces 32-bit code) this will probably be substantially faster if you use `mt19937` instead of `mt19937_64`. This will only have 32 bits of randomness for each generated number, but that's probably as much as `rand()` produces anyway. On a 64-bit system/compiler, expect `mt19937_64` to run just as fast, and produce substantially greater randomness.

One other minor note: here I've just used the default seed (which is `1`) for each generator. You may want to generate seeds randomly, such as from `std::random_device`, and seed each thread's generator separately so you don't get duplication of numbers between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `rand` is not thread safe. A simple alternative is `drand48_r` for what I was trying to use. Changing my loop as follows shows the exact speedup I was expecting:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(ii, rBuf, trand) shared(xs,ys)
    for(ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {
        drand48_r(&rBuf, &trand);
        xs[ii] = trand;
        drand48_r(&rBuf, &trand);
        ys[ii] = trand;
    }
```